# Regular expression find alphanumerics with slash at the end

Tags: regex

Let's say some strings like the following:

- a2gh5/r6kl/kd049/fg7j
- ykl96/s8sd/5gjh8/1xl98

I just made those up...and I want to get the first two sets of the alphanumeric values without the slash at the end like this:

- a2gh5/r6kl
- ykl96/s8sd

I have tried things like:

- [a-zA-Z0-9]+/
- [a-zA-Z0-9]
- [a-zA-Z0-9/]
- [a-zA-Z0-9]{1}*/
- ^(?!/[A-Za-z0-9]{2}/).*/

I tried just matching one set followed by a slash and worked my way into this:

- ^(?!.*?/[A-Za-z0-9]/$).*?/

but I can't seem to find out how to include two since I am not taking the slash at the front any more on the last expression...I am using [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com) to test.

Comment: Go simple `[a-zA-Z0-9]+/[a-zA-Z0-9]+`

Comment: I can't believe I didn't do that in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex:

```
^([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+).*
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/nE8jF9/1)

`[^\/]` means not slash characters and `+` means at least one.